# Introspection Bug - Looks for django_migrations at the Database Level Instead of Schema Level

Tags: python, sql-server, django, python-3.x, django-pyodbc-azure

**Update 6:** After discussing the issue on the IRC #django, I think `django-pyodbc-azure` is introspecting the database and looking for `django_migrations` at the database level, not the schema level. Therefore, it's finding it at the database level (from the original app), and therefore cannot create it. This might be a bug in the introspection of `django-pyodbc-azure`.

**Update 5:** I have triple checked the schemas, and they are identical besides the name. I also updated `django-pyodbc-azure` and `django` to the latest 1.11 versions. I am at a loss.

**Update 4:** I added a table called `django_migrations` to the new schema, and the error changed to `invalid column name 'app'`. So it seems like the tables are expected to be there initially. However, as mentioned in my original question, this is impossible and not how it has been done in the past.

**Update 3:** No other schema works except the schema for the original project (which already has tables, including django_migrations). When that schema was created, it did not have any tables in it prior to running things like `python manage.py runserver`.

**UPDATE 2:** The schema difference is the root issue. I changed the default schema of the original user to the new default schema I want the new app to use, and the same error occurred. Why is one schema working, and the other is not?

**UPDATE:** It seems to be a problem with the different users. Both users have the same SQL Server permissions. Each user has a different default schema that was created for this purpose. The user for the original project has tables (including django_migrations) already in the database.

**Original:**

Python: 3.6.4

django: 1.11.9

django-pyodbc-azure: 1.11.9

I have a django project (`myProject`) with one django app (`myApp`). This project is run on a conda environment that includes `django-pyodbc-azure` to connect to SQL Server.

The only changes made from the default setup are the following:

1. Added `myApp.apps.MyAppConfig` to `INSTALLED_APPS`
2. Changed `DATABASES` to this:

   ```
   DATABASES = {
   'default': {
       'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
       'HOST': 'hostname',
       'NAME': 'databasename',
       'USER': 'username',
       'PASSWORD': 'password',
       'OPTIONS': {
           'driver': 'SQL Server Native Client 11.0'
       },
   },
   }
   ```

When I attempt to run `python manage.py runserver`, the following error occurs:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\pathtodjangoproject\myProject>activate myApp

(myApp) C:\pathtodjangoproject\myProject>python manage.py runserver
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper
 at 0x000000000422A378>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\pathtoanaconda\anaconda\envs\myApp\lib\site-packages\django\db
\backends\utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\pathtoanaconda\anaconda\envs\myApp\lib\site-packages\sql_serve
r\pyodbc\base.py", line 545, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42S02', "[42S02] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client
 11.0][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'django_migrations'. (208) (SQLExecDirectW
)")

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\pathtoanaconda\anaconda\envs\myApp\lib\site-packages\django\ut
ils\autoreload.py", line 228, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\pathtoanaconda\anaconda\envs\myApp\lib\site-packages\django\co
re\management\commands\runserver.py", line 128, in inner_run
    self.check_migrations()
  File "C:\pathtoanaconda\anaconda\envs\myApp\lib\site-packages\django\co
re\management\base.py", line 422, in check_migrations
    executor = MigrationExecutor(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS])
  File "C:\pathtoanaconda\anaconda\envs\myApp\lib\site-packages\django\db
\migrations\executor.py", line 20, in __init__
    self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
  File "C:\pathtoanaconda\anaconda\envs\myApp\lib\site-packages\django\db
\migrations\loader.py", line 52, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "C:\pathtoanaconda\anaconda\envs\myApp\lib\site-packages\django\db
\migrations\loader.py", line 209, in build_graph
    self.applied_migrations = recorder.applied_migrations()
  File "C:\pathtoanaconda\anaconda\envs\myApp\lib\site-packages\django\db
\migrations\recorder.py", line 66, in applied_migrations
    return set(tuple(x) for x in self.migration_qs.values_list("app", "name"))
  File "C:\pathtoanaconda\anaconda\envs\myApp\lib\site-packages\django\db
\models\query.py", line 250, in __iter__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "C:\pathtoanaconda\anaconda\envs\myApp\lib\site-packages\django\db
\models\query.py", line 1118, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "C:\pathtoanaconda\anaconda\envs\myApp\lib\site-packages\django\db
\models\query.py", line 122, in __iter__
    for row in compiler.results_iter(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch):
  File "C:\pathtoanaconda\anaconda\envs\myApp\lib\site-packages\django\db
\models\sql\compiler.py", line 841, in results_iter
    results = self.execute_sql(MULTI, chunked_fetch=chunked_fetch)
  File "C:\pathtoanaconda\anaconda\envs\myApp\lib\site-packages\django\db
\models\sql\compiler.py", line 899, in execute_sql
    raise original_exception
  File "C:\pathtoanaconda\anaconda\envs\myApp\lib\site-packages\django\db
\models\sql\compiler.py", line 889, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\pathtoanaconda\anaconda\envs\myApp\lib\site-packages\django\db
\backends\utils.py", line 79, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\pathtoanaconda\anaconda\envs\myApp\lib\site-packages\django\db
\backends\utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\pathtoanaconda\anaconda\envs\myApp\lib\site-packages\django\db
\utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "C:\pathtoanaconda\anaconda\envs\myApp\lib\site-packages\django\ut
ils\six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "C:\pathtoanaconda\anaconda\envs\myApp\lib\site-packages\django\db
\backends\utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\pathtoanaconda\anaconda\envs\myApp\lib\site-packages\sql_serve
r\pyodbc\base.py", line 545, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: ('42S02', "[42S02] [Microsoft][SQL Server Nati
ve Client 11.0][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'django_migrations'. (208) (SQLEx
ecDirectW)")
```

Why is this issue occurring, and how do I fix it? It seems like it is looking for `django_migrations` in the database, but no tables have been created yet. In fact, tables can't be created because `python manage.py makemigrations` causes the same error.

This is the second django project I've built. The first runs flawlessly with the same `DATABASES` settings (besides being a different user to get a different default schema) and the same environment.

Answer (score 0):

Did you create the database ? If I recall correctly you need to do that manually. Also see this issue: https://github.com/michiya/django-pyodbc-azure/issues/103

Comment: the database already exists, yes. it is our main database, i just have a default schema set for the username. this is the same way i handled the previous project without issue.